# Why is python unable to detect notification module in plyer?

Tags: python, windows

I can't get this simple statement to work:

```
from plyer import notification
```

getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'notification'
```

the import statement is correct and is used the same way in examples.
I couldn't find any special instructions to use this library so I'm assuming there aren't any.

I installed plyer using pip and it installed successfully. verified the files are in place. I tried using python 3.5 and 3.6, same result.
It seems the package is recognized but just the module isnt found?

Would appreciate some insight :)

Comment: Could it be that you have a script or module named "plyer.py" before the location of the real `plyer` module in you sys.path ? Try to add this before (or instead of) : `import plyer; print(plyer)` and check what it prints.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that was it, i named the script i was testing it 'plyer.py'. renamed the file and problem was solved. silly me, thanks :)

Comment: That's a common gotcha indeed. As a general rule when you have such kind of problems the first think to check is whether what you have (here the `plyer.py` script shadowing the `plyer` package) is really what you expect it to be ;)

Comment: Added a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common cause for this kind of problem is having a script or module by the same name in a location that comes before the expected module or package's location in `sys.path` so it gets imported instead of the expected module or package.

The simple way to sort this out is to add this simple line before:

```
import plyer; print(plyer);
```

and check the result which will diplay the path of whatever named `plyer` was first found. Chances are it's a script in your current working directory...